# how to get last selected option in multiple select in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the last selected `<option>` in a `<select multiple>` in javascript not jquery!

> The last selected option means the last option selected by the user.
> Not that the last option element in the select element!

I try:

```
<select multiple="multiple" onchange="changeEvent(this)">

function changeEvent(selectTag) {
    console.log(selectTag.value);
}
```

I expected to get the last `<option>` selected

Comment: Do you mean the last selected option in the list or the last option selected by the user? What do you mean by "current selected" because all the selected options are considered the current selection.

Comment: @Yogi I mean the last selected `<option>` by user

Comment: You can do this by using the click as that will give you the last option selected.  You will need to store the values in an array so that if the user unselects an option you can rollback to the previous value.  See this [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/1bcghfxy/show) on how to do it.

Comment: @Yogi Yes, that's exactly what I meant, I got my correct answer from you.

Answer (score 2):

The value property of the select tag only returns the value of the selected option if the **multiple attribute is not set**. If the multiple attribute is set, you can use the options property of the `<select>` element to get an array of all the options and check which ones are selected.

Here's an updated version of the function with **JavaScript**:

```js
function changeEvent(selectTag) {
    let selectedOptions = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < selectTag.options.length; i++) {
        if (selectTag.options[i].selected) {
            selectedOptions.push(selectTag.options[i].value);
        }
    }
    console.log(selectedOptions);
}
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple" onchange="changeEvent(this)">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I edited my question, please edit your answer

Answer (score 2):

To get all the selected options, use [`selectedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) on the `selectTag`.

For the 'last' option, use the default `selectTag.value`.

Remember that `.value` will only contain the last selected value, so if you'd un-select some value, the previous selected will be set as value of `selectTag.value`

```js
function changeEvent(selectTag) {
    const allSelectedValues = Array.from(selectTag.selectedOptions).map(t => t.value).join(', ');
    console.log(`All selected: ${allSelectedValues}`);
    console.log(`Previous: ${selectTag.value}`);
}
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple" onchange="changeEvent(this)">
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
  <option>foobar</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I edited my question, please edit your answer for the `pop()`

Comment: Changed my answer.